# Call Partial View using @Url.Action() from razor and Ajax separately

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a `SearchStudent()` action, there should be something wrong with my code, something that I'm missing, I've an action method that returns a `Partial View`, I want to show first the `Partial View Page` inside the `Index page` with the `Search` form and once filled the form submit it using a `Post request`. I want to do all that using ajax so I want all that to happen inside the `Index view`..
I know that is a bad practice to hardcode our url from ajax, so I'm using the `data-` attribute from my razor view inside a `<p>` element putting in there the url using `@Url.Action()`. The thing is that when I use `@Url.Action` it routes to the Index action instead of the `SearchStudent() Action` and shows the same `Index page` twice instead of the `partial view` and when I hardcode in ajax the url then it recognizes it, what's happening?

Maybe you'll understand better seeing my code:

Action Method(I want to show the partial view first)

```
 public PartialViewResult SearchStudent()
        {            
            return PartialView();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult SearchStudent(string name)
        {
            List<Student> list = db.Students.Where(s => s.Name == name).ToList();
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Index view(just the section concerning to show the Partial View):

```
<div>
    <p class="hand" id="pSearch" data-urlSearch="@Url.Action("SearchStudent","Students")"> Search by name</p>
    <div id="ShowFormSearch"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery function(if I put directly inside ajax `url: "Students/SearchStudent"` it works but that is not a good practice):

```
function ShowSearchPage()

{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: $("#pSearch").data('urlSearch'),        
    }).success(function (result) {
        $("#ShowFormSearch").html(result)
    }).error(function () {
        $("#ShowFormSearch").html("An error occurred")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `$("#pSearch").data('urlSearch')` is not returning `Students/SearchStudent`. The reason is, for HTML 5 data attrbutes, it should be **lowercase**.

Replace

```
$("#pSearch").data('urlSearch')
```

with

```
$("#pSearch").data('urlsearch')
```

Also i recommend using lowercase always for setting the data attrbute.

```
data-urlsearch="@Url.Action("SearchStudent", "Home")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing your javascript function like this and let us know what the results are:

```
function ShowSearchPage() {

    var url = $("#pSearch").data('urlSearch');
    alert(url);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: url,
    }).success(function (result) {
        $("#ShowFormSearch").html(result)
    }).error(function () {
        $("#ShowFormSearch").html("An error occurred")
    })
}
```

Comment: That's because data attributes should always be typed in lower case.Just change it to - var url = $("#pSearch").data('urlsearch');